# Android Studio CPU Profiler: "No data available for the selected time frame"

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler

I use Android Studio 3.6.3 on Ubuntu workstation. Recently, I needed to find a bottleneck in the code of my application. I launched the profiler and tried to record application activity using Trace Java Methods option. 
Faced a problem: only part of the application activity is recorded (for some reason, only the first "peaks" of application activity). For the remaining "peaks", the message "No data available for the selected time frame" is shown.

[image: first "peak" - methods timings recorded]
[image: second "peak" - no data available]
[image: third "peak" - also no data available]

How to solve this problem?

Tried to use Android Studio CPU Profiler on Windows 10 workstation - the same problem.

Are the alternatives to Android Studio's CPU Profiler to do the same thing?